# Change filename when file drops into folder

Tags: c#

I'm new at c#. I want to be able to drag and drop some .MSG files into a folder and I'd like to change the filenames uniquely. I've no idea what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If the file name isn't unique, then it'll be pretty hard to drop it into the folder in the first place - but that's beside the point.

You can watch a folder using the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class. You can generate a unique name in a number of ways - something involving `Guid.NewGuid()` will always work of course.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Filenames may not be unique unfotunately and you're right it's not easy to change a file's name but there must be a good way or trick to do it. Do you have any source about it?